# Lightweight Django: settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS set as environment variable

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I'm following Lightweight Django by Julia Elman and Mark Lavin, from O'Reilly. On Chapter 1, I can't set ALLOWED_HOSTS as an environment variable.

When I run `python hello.py runserver`, I keep have the `CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False`

This is my `hello.py`:

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', 'on') == 'on'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', os.urandom(32))
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', 'localhost').split(',')

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=DEBUG,
    SECRET_KEY=SECRET_KEY,
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ),
)

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', index),
)

application = get_wsgi_application()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I've done the `export DEBUG=off`, and `export ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com`
and I'm sure I have the environment variable:

```
$printenv DEBUG
off
$printenv ALLOWED_HOSTS
localhost,example.com
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add `ALLOWED_HOSTS` argument into the `settings.configure()` call.

Comment: but after I add it, I can't go to the same `Hello World`, instead I get a `Bad Request (400)`, can you also tell me why? Thx!!

Comment: This is because of host name mismatch in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and browser url.  Add `127.0.0.1` to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` environment variable or point your browser to `http://localhost:8000`.